# Google Chrome CORB issue

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, cross-origin-read-blocking

When using Google Chrome and running my frontend locally, I try to call my backend which is also running locally, the response is returned empty with the below warning:

[image]

This has only started happening recently. I have all the following headers:
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"`
`Content-Type: "application/json"`
`X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"`.

But there is still no response. It was working fine up until a few weeks ago. Does anyone know if the Chrome security settings have changed in the past few weeks, and how I can overcome this issue?

Steps to reproduce:
 - Run frontend locally using chrome, using the the above headers
 - Run backend using chrome
 - Call an endpoint which should provide a response

Comment: try installing CORS Extension in google chrome

Comment: The error message has a link to a chromestatus entry where you can see the documentation about this change in Chrome 72 as well as possible solutions. To get help on StackOverflow you need to provide [MCVE](/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: I have the CORS extension and the above headers. It is a large project I have been working on for some time and this issue is very recent.

Comment: I have checked the error message, but it just says to add the headers that I already have (see above)

Comment: There's a link for extensions-specific solutions: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches